# In WPF how does Panel render its content?

Tags: wpf, templates, panel, render

I know you can inherit from the [Panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel(v=vs.110).aspx) class and use the (MeasureOverride  and ArrangeOverride) to measure and arrange the UI-Elements. But how does the Panel class render its content without any template?
Panel inherits from the FrameworkElement class which does not have the concept of template. So what causes it to render?

Comment: The WPF `Panel` does not deal with rendering. It deals with *layout* only. These are separate things in WPF. The Panel simply defines the positions of it's *Visual Children*, which in turn are rendered in the rendering pass once the layout pass is completed.

Comment: So what is responsible for rendering the content. If I make a class that inherits from the FrameworkElement beside the OnRender method, how can I render another control on it. Is that even possible?.